# How would one replace a string in a list with another string based on the location of the string in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and am currently working on a battleship game (not codecademy) for a computer science class. I was wondering what would be the best way to replace a item in a list based on its location in the list, with another item.

For example

```
board_row_1 = ['0','0','0','0','0']
# Would want to replace item 2 with an 'x'
```

Cant really find an answer to this anywhere on the internet. Unlike replacing a certain string/integer, I am replacing it based on the location of the item.

Comment: just board_row_1[1] = 'x'

Comment: If it's been solved and there's no answer, add your own and accept it.  Don't add "solved" to your title.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to replace items in the same list the best way is this :

```
board_row_1[x],board_row_1[y]=board_row_1[y],board_row_1[x]
```